# What is the correct term for a script in computing?

Tags: informatique, terminologie

I'd like to know what the correct term for a script (or shell script) is in French. It is a bit like a program, but with subtle differences.

I've been translating this as 'le script' in French, but am aware that this refers to handwritten lettering. What is the correct word to use?

Comment: Saying "le script" for a handwritten letter is only used in historical contexts. You won't hear anyone say "le script" to mean something he handwrote nowadays. And if you are talking about "le script shell", the context will make it clear you are talking about programming.

Comment: Note also that outside the software jargon, *script* in well known and used in French as a synonym of *scenario*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Très majoritairement, le mot « script », repris directement de l'anglais, est utilisé. [Même au Québec](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8367275), c'est le terme officiel.

Comment: Effectivement. Les langages utilisés sont même appelés [langages de script](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_de_script).